# How to input one letter at a time in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I want to take one letter at a time in python. can we take one letter at a time using "**input()**" in python3

Example: I want to input only one letter such as a. b, c, .....etc. It should not accept more than one letter word such as ab, as, asa ... etc.
is there any such function in python 3?

Comment: you may want a lower level keyboard input method, like`_getch()` on windows.

Comment: No, not really. `input` accepts any number of characters. The best you could do is simply slice off the first character of each inputted string.

Comment: You could read one character from `sys.stdin`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`getch`](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) module.

```
import getch
# ...
char = getch.getch() # User input, but not displayed on the screen
# or
char = getch.getche() # also displayed on the screen
```

Comment: that's a good answer, but can you post it in the duplicate link instead? and notify me when you've done so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this  code:

```
a=input()[0]
print(a)
```

a will be first char but if you want to force user to enter one letter you can use **getch**